# How do you I determine where Integer(string) method belongs to?

Tags: ruby

In this code:

```
Integer("1234")
```

Is Integer a method of a module, or class?  How do I see its documentation?

When I write code like:

```
"1234".to_i
```

I could simply use *ri to_i* in command shell to see the internal documentation of the method to_i.

Comment: `p method(:Integer).owner # => Kernel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [`Kernel#Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method. Most methods that you can use anywhere without an explicit callee (like `Integer`, `Array`, `puts`, `sleep`, etc.) belong to Kernel. You can see the docs for it by typing `ri Kernel#Integer` or, as a shortcut, `ri #Integer` or `ri .Integer`.

Comment: My reading of the question is that OP is asking how to find any method's owner (as @cremno suggested in a comment), `Integer` just being an example. Note also the second example, `"1234".to_i`. (Hmmm, maybe not. I just reread the question's title. My interpretation is more interesting though.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I tried ri #method but it don't work, ri .method worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To tell whether it is a method or a constant, you don't need to see anything further.

A constant (including class) never takes an argument. So if you see a form **with parentheses**:

```
Foo()
Foo(some_argument)
```

you can immediately tell it is a **method** call.

And a method that is potentially ambiguous with a constant requires parentheses (even when there is no argument). Therefore, if you see a form **without parentheses**:

```
Foo
```

you can immediately tell it is a **constant** (such as a class).

To tell where the method is defined, the standard way is to use `owner`.

```
method(:Integer).owner # => Kernel
```